# Akka: how to unit testing OneForOneStrategy?

Tags: scala, akka

I am trying to unit testing a very simple parent/child supervised relationship with OneForOneStrategy:

```
class MySupervisor() extends Actor {

  val child = createChild()

  override val supervisorStrategy: SupervisorStrategy = {
    val decider: SupervisorStrategy.Decider = {
      case SomethingWrongException(request) =>
        child ! request
        SupervisorStrategy.Resume
    }
    OneForOneStrategy()(decider orElse super.supervisorStrategy.decider)
  }
...
}
```

The problem is I can not find any valid example about how to do this (possibly for other supervised strategies too).

Any hints?

Comment: what exactly do you want to test in that unit test? what do you mean by "very simple parent/child supervised relationship with OneForOneStrategy"

Answer (score 0):

Here's the akka document for the strategy for supervisor. The section of Test Application describe some samples about how to test with the strategy.

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/fault-tolerance.html

Answer (score 0):

This [file](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor-tests/src/test/scala/akka/actor/SupervisorSpec.scala) in the akka test source should help.